# Dynamically pass parameter to web service on react js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two dropdowns, Discount Type and Offer Type, Discount type returns four elements so what I want to do is for example if I select option number 2 from that dropdown then call the URL that populates the Offer Type dropdown with the selected index, in this case '2', because now the offer type is returning all because I'm using the following URL that brings all: `http://xxxxxx:8080/services/OfferType/getAll` but instead of getAll I want to pass the index of the Offer Type Dropdown to have something like this `http://xxxxxx:8080/services/OfferType/2`

Any help on how to do this because I don't, below you'll find my current code:

```
import React from 'react';

import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';

import cr from '../styles/general.css';

export default class ExampleDropdown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DiscountTypeData: [],
      OfferTypeData: [],
      DiscountTypeState: '',
      OfferTypeState: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.renderDiscountTypeOptions = this.renderDiscountTypeOptions.bind(this);
    this.renderOfferTypeOptions = this.renderOfferTypeOptions.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeDiscountType = this.handleChangeDiscountType.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeOfferType = this.handleChangeOfferType.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const offerTypeWS = 'http://xxxxxx:8080/services/OfferType/getAll';
    const discountTypeWS = 'http://xxxxxx:8080/services/DiscountType/getAll';

    fetch(offerTypeWS)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          OfferTypeData: findResponse.offerTypes
        });
      });

    fetch(discountTypeWS)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          DiscountTypeData: findResponse.discountTypes
        });
      });
  }

  handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value});
  }

  handleChangeDiscountType(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ DiscountTypeState: (value) });
  }

  handleChangeOfferType(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ OfferTypeState: (value) });
  }

  renderDiscountTypeOptions() {
    return this.state.DiscountTypeData.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={i}
          value={dt.text}
          primaryText={dt.text} />
      );
    });
  }

  renderOfferTypeOptions() {
    return this.state.OfferTypeData.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={i}
          value={dt.offerTypeDesc}
          primaryText={dt.offerTypeDesc} />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className={cr.container}>
        <div className ={cr.boton}>
          <Divider/>
          <br/>
        </div>
          <div>
            <DropDownMenu
              value={this.state.DiscountTypeState}
              onChange={this.handleChangeDiscountType}>
              <MenuItem value={''} primaryText={'Select discount type'} />
              {this.renderDiscountTypeOptions()}
            </DropDownMenu>
            <br/>
            <DropDownMenu
              value={this.state.OfferTypeState}
              onChange={this.handleChangeOfferType}>
              <MenuItem value={''} primaryText={'Select offer type'} />
              {this.renderOfferTypeOptions()}
            </DropDownMenu>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the response from the Discount Type service:

[image]

So if I select "Bulk Discount" that has the value "3" then I want to pass that 3 to the Offer Type URL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `fetch` from `handleChangeDiscountType` or `handleChangeOfferType` just like you called in componentDidMount. Example:

```
handleChangeDiscountType(event, index, value) {
   fetch('http://xxxxxx:8080/services/DiscountType/' + value.id)
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);
        this.setState({ DiscountTypeState: findResponse });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, then I can remove the fetch method from componentDidMount for this two WS and then fetch on handleChange methods right??

Comment: Hey Tamir, I just update the question, at the end I add more detail, maybe that helps...

Comment: 1. I guess you would still need the fetch methods because I'm assuming you want to show the user all of the options before he chooses a specific one.


2. Following your post update with the service response, you would have to use value.id instead of value in the code snippet I wrote